# Searching for an alternative for strtok() in C++

Tags: c++, split, strtok

I am using strtok to divide a string in several parts.
In this example, all sections will be read from the string, which are bounded by a colon or a semicolon

```
char string[] = "Alice1:IscoolAlice2; Alert555678;Bob1:knowsBeepBob2;sees";
char delimiter[] = ":;";
char *p;

p = strtok(string, delimiter);

while(p != NULL) {
    cout << "Result: " << p << endl;

    p = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
}
```

As results I get:

```
Result: Alice1
Result: IscoolAlice2
Result:  Alert555678
Result: Bob1
Result: knowsBeepBob2
Result: sees
```

But I would like to get this results:

```
Result: Alice1:
Result: Alice2;
Result: Bob1:
Result: Bob2;
```

The restriction is that I can only choose individual characters when I use strtok.
Does anyone know an alternative for strtok that I also can search for strings?
Or has anyone an idea to solve my problem?

Comment: How do you plan to separate the word Iscool from Alice2? There's no gap.

Comment: You probably want [`boost::tokenizer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html).

Comment: I think you need to provide a clearer problem statement. You appear to be looking for things that come after or before : delimited by ; and then taking everything after and including the last capital letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can not do that task with `strtok` since you need more complex search

Although I am not sure what is your `string` as delimiter but the same output can be done with:

```
char string[] = "Alice1:IscoolAlice2; Alert555678;Bob1:knowsBeepBob2;sees";
char delimiter[] = "(?:Alice|Bob)\\d.";
std::regex regex( delimiter );
std::regex_iterator< const char* > first( std::begin( string ), std::end( string ), regex  ), last;

while( first != last ){
    std::cout << "Result: " << first->str() << '\n';
    ++first;
}
```

**the output:**

```
Result: Alice1;
Result: Alice2;
Result: Bob1;
Result: Bob2;
```

Comment: Thank you very much k-five! It´s exactly that what I´ve needed!

Comment: @Kadamu Not a Problem

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with your stated data set to properly split it the way you want. You can come up with a "just so" rule to split literally just the data you showed, but given the messy nature of the data it's highly likely it'll fail on other examples. Let's start with this token.

```
IscoolAlice2
```

How is a computer program supposed to know which part of this is the name and which is not? You want to get "Alice2" out of this. If you decide that a capital letter specifies a name then it will just spit out the "name" IscoolAlice2. The same with:

```
knowsBeepBob2
```

If you search for the first capital letter then the program will decide his name is BeepBob2, so in each case searching for the last occurance of a capital letter in the token finds the name. But what if a name contains two capital letters? The program will cut their name off and you can't do anything about that.

If you're happy to live with these sorts of limitations you can do an initial split via strtok using only the ; character, which gives:

```
Alice1:IscoolAlice2
 Alert555678
Bob1:knowsBeepBob2
sees
```

Which is less than ideal. You could then specify a rule such that a name exists in any row which contains a : taking anything left of the : as a name, and then finding the last capital letter and anything from that point is also a name. That would give you the output you desire.

But the rules I outlined are extremely specific to the data that was just fed in. If anything about other samples of data deviates at all from this (e.g. a name with two capitals in it) then it will fail as there will be no way on Earth the program could determine where the "name" starts.

The only way to fix this is to go back to where the data is coming from and format it differently so that there is some sort of punctuation before the names.

Or alternatively you need a full database of all possible names that could appear, then search for them, find any characters up to the next : or ; and append them and print the name. But that seems extremely impractical.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a simple bit of scratch logic, along these lines:

```
char *ptr = string;

while(*ptr)
{
   printf("Result:");
   while(*ptr)
   {
      printf("%c", *ptr);
      if(ispunc(*ptr))
      {
         ptr++;
         printf("\n");
         break;
      }
      else
      {
         ptr++;
      }
   }
}
```